# Slave isn't writing any data into the table in mysql master slave replication

Tags: mysql, amazon-web-services, phpmyadmin, database-replication, master-slave

I am having a difficult time in setting Master-Slave configuration.

Master Database runs on Ubuntu( Amazon AWS instance) and successfully set-up master replication.

I have localhost as a Slave Server. (Windows Machine).

**Snapshot of Master Database**
[image: Master Replication]

**Master database has record**
[image: Master Replication has 34 tables]

**Binar Log Information**
[image: Binary Log]

**Process List on Master Replication**
[image]

**Status of Master Replication**
[image]

I debug master replication which works okay I guess.

On the Salve Side:
**Status on Slave Side**
[image: Status on Slave Replication]

Even though MASTER_LOG and MASTER_POS are synced but data doesn't.

Currently, I have 0 table on Slave side and 34 tables on Master side.

**Tables on Slave side** 
[image]

I am open to any suggestion or any reference do you have.

I spend an entire day and trying to find what I did wrong.
I want to Sync my Local database with a database hosted on remote-server.

**Update: Thigs I did to debug the Master-Slave Replication**

1. Checked Master Database is up and running.
2. Master Status and Connected Slaves. [Which includes unique id for
   each server.]
3. Slave database is up and running [Including Slave IO Thread and
   SQL thread is running.]

These three steps ensure that Master-Slave replication is up and running without any problem.

*Handling Data Sync Problem*

1. Created/update/delete data in the master database to check
   whether data is sync on a server or not.
2. Checked Binary Log [Specifically I checked the file size. If I
   entered data file size will continuously increasing.]

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Hi, we had similar problem - read more about gotchas in "binlog-do-db" and "replication-do-db" and related parameters - https://www.percona.com/blog/2009/05/14/why-mysqls-binlog-do-db-option-is-dangerous/ - here is a big problem with crossdatabase references. At the and we had to remove these settings limiting replication.

Comment: Thanks @JosMac I'll give it a try and will let you know.

Comment: @JosMac Thanks buddy! You're a lifesaver. Can you please write it in the answer and I'll accept it. binlog_ignore_db is problematic statement. Once I removed it and restart the server everything is in sync.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

we had similar problem - read more about gotchas in "binlog-do-db" and "replication-do-db" and related parameters. Here is a big problem with crossdatabase references. At the and we had to remove these settings limiting replication.

- [Why MySQL’s binlog-do-db option is dangerous](https://www.percona.com/blog/2009/05/14/why-mysqls-binlog-do-db-option-is-dangerous/)
- [Gotchas in MySQL replication](http://mysql.freeideas.cz/subdom/mysql/2016/07/05/gotchas-in-mysql-replication/)

Answer (score 0):

As your show slave status output says you enabled Replicate_DO_DB for the DB "Arihantpos" at the same time you did Binglog_Do_Db for the same db

try to remove Binglog_Do_Db from config file and restart mysql and start replication again